# Performing T-Test with elements with multiple attributes

Tags: t-test

For an archaeology project, I have two assemblages of items, each measured in a variety of ways (mass, area, thickness, etc.).

I want to test if the differences between the assemblages are significant.

I am pretty sure I have to use the T-Test, but I am not sure how to apply it, taking into account all of the various attributes of each item. Do I perform the T-Test for each attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have several measures on each item, this is a multivariate problem. The appropriate test (assuming that your data are approximately multivariate normal) is [Hotelling's T^2 test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution).